# WordPress how to disable a plugin for one page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ask you how can I disable Age Verifier plugin for terms and condition page in WordPress? Is there any function I can use?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

try "Plugin Organizer" Wordpress plugin by Jeff Sterup. You have to enable "Selective Plugin Loading" under it's settings (make sure to follow their directions given for enabling it)

Then in your post/page editor there is a box below the compose window with tickboxes to disable whichever particular plugin for that page